# Does a brother counts as close family for immigration to Canada?

Tags: immigration, canada

I am applying to immigrate to Canada. It would be great if I could take my brother along with me. I am single. Can I take my brother along with me? Would he be considred family?

Answer (score 7):

A sibling does not count. Here's the [list](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=343&top=14):

> These family members can come with you:
>
> - your spouse or common-law partner,
> - your dependent child,
> - your spouse or common-law partner’s dependent child, and
> - a dependent child of a dependent child.
>
> These family members can’t come with you:
>
> - your parents,
> - grandparents,
> - brother or sister,
> - uncle or aunt,
> - nephew or niece, or
> - other relatives.
>
> You may be able to sponsor them **after** you immigrate to Canada.

After you become a permanent resident or citizen, you would only be able to sponsor your brother if he's under 18, orphaned, and not married/partnered/etc.